# Is dependency injection possible for plugins?

Tags: magento2, plugin, dependency-injection, di

I'm trying to make a plugin to extend the \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator

Which works like a charm, but the problem is I need to make use of Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory

I've tried making a __constructor in the plugin class and adding the RuleFactory there through dependency injection as described in het Magento 2 Developer Guide which looked like this:

The entire "Validator" plugin class now looks like this:

```
class Validator{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory
     */
    public function __constructor(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory){
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        error_log('validator constructed');
    }

    public function aroundInit(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator $subject, $procede, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $couponCode){
        //custom before code
        $return = $proceed($websiteId, $customerGroupId, $couponCode);
        //custom after code
        return $return;
    }
}
```

but this would just return null for $this->ruleFactory at all times.

the di.xml document contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator">
        <plugin name="ValidatorPlugin" type="\MAS\CouponAttempt\Model\SalesRule\Validator" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
    <type name="\MAS\CouponAttempt\Model\SalesRule\Validator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="ruleFactoryInjection" xsi:type="object">Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Interestingly enough I found that in the generated Interceptor.php file the constructor is actually made. But it is never called, can anybody tell me why this could be?

Comment: Clear contents of `var/generation`

Comment: I did, and after your comment i checked the interceptor file and interestingly enough I did find the following: 
    public function __constructor(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory)
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, '__constructor');
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::__constructor($ruleFactory);
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('__constructor', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        }
    }

Comment: So it's actually being generated but the constructor is not being called (still not getting an error_log entry and the $ruleFactory is still not defined), any thoughts?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I decided to go with the less clean solution and just used a static instance of the objectmanager and got the rule factory through that

Comment: Not recommended by magento

Answer (score 16):

Late answer but you need to change `__constructor` to `__construct` and it will work perfectly well. Don't use static ObjectManager if possible. You should always use DI instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is supported.
Looks like in your sample `function` keyword is missing, try:

```
public function __constructor(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory){
    $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this was however merely an oversight while typing up this post, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Try to post the whole plugin content here.

Comment: Done, quick note the >error_log('validator constructed'); never happens either

Comment: Do you need my di.xml content aswell?

Comment: yes, would be nice, so it is possible to reproduce issue.

Comment: Bit of a late comment, but I added it :)