# Add CC to all transactional emails in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, plugin

I wanna add custom CC email to all transactional emails in Magento 2. But, I can't find any decent event to catch email sending process and add CC to email. Any ideas?

UPDATE

As Keyur Shah suggests, I've created di.xml

```
<config>
<type name="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder">
  <plugin name="test_custompayment_plugin" type="Test\Custompayment\Plugin\TransportBuilder" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

And /Test/Custompayment/Plugin/TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\Custompayment\Plugin;

class TransportBuilder
{
public function beforeGetTransport()
{
    $this->prepareMessage();
    $this->addCc('sevkafaya@gmail.com','');
    $mailTransport = $this->mailTransportFactory->create(['message' => clone $this->message]);
    $this->reset();
    return $mailTransport;
   }
}
```

But I face with error:

> Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Test\Custompayment\Plugin\TransportBuilder::prepareMessage()

So do I need copy all content from `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` and just replace `getTransport()` with `beforeGetTransport`?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Still not, but will try today. Thanks. Will appreciate if you demonstrate di.xml for overriding TransportBuilder class

Comment: I already gave a link in my answer, you can try it your end. Still, If you face any problem then just let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento2 use `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` to configure and send an email so I would suggest you to write a `before` [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for this [class](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php#L19) and and method is [getTransport()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php#L227) method.

On before plugin you can add your custom email address as [addCc()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php#L117).

Answer (score 2):

This feature is built into Magento core

You have the option to configure cc for many of the different transactional emails

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use **after** method

```
    public function afterGetTransport($subject, $result) 
{
    $result->getMessage()->addCc('sevkafaya@gmail.com','');     
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vitalli
I have tried your way but it not working. can you share your complete code here? 
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Hi, today it depends on the magento version: 4 ranges 2.0.1-2.2.6, 2.2.7-2.3.3, 2.3.4-2.3. *, 2.4 * have different solutions  ...

Answer (score 1):

@keyur-shah 's answer definitely gave me the clue. I share my result here - just in case anyone needs it. As suggested, I have created a plugin that hooks into the `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\getTransport` method via a `before` hook.

I also made the cc address configurable via admin. For this purpose, I needed dependency injection and an additional constructor.  [Is dependency injection possible for plugins?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92087/is-dependency-injection-possible-for-plugins) helped me with this.

This is my core plugin file:

`CcPlugin.php:`

```
<?php
/**
 * MyCompany Email.
 */

namespace MyCompany\Email\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

/**
 * Class CcPlugin.
 */
class CcPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * CcPlugin constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                           $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Set cc for transactional emails, if configured via admin.
     */
    public function beforeGetTransport(TransportBuilder $subject)
    {
        try {
            $path = 'email/general/cc';
            if ($this->scopeConfig) {
                $ccEmailAddress = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    $path,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                );
                if (!empty($ccEmailAddress)) {
                    $subject->addCc($ccEmailAddress);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error('Failure in MyCompany Cc module: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        return [];
    }
}
```

The `di.xml` file was required for the plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * MyCompany Email.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder">
        <plugin name="mycompany_email" type="MyCompany\Email\Plugin\CcPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Finally, I added a field to the admin configuration via `system.xml`. You need to fit this into an existing `system.xml`, as it is just an excerpt of a larger system.xml in my case.

```
    <section id="email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Emails</label>
        <tab>mycompany</tab>
        <resource>MyCompany_Email::config_section</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General Settings</label>
            <field id="cc" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1">
                <label>CC Email Address</label>
                <comment>A cc copy of any transactional email will be sent to this address. Leave empty to switch off.</comment>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
```